# Smart Contract management

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I'm new to blockchain development.
I watched a lot of udemy courses about Solidity.

I think I understand how smart contracts work but I have 2 questions.

Would it be possible to manage an application which uses a smart contract without forcing users to have ethereum wallet ?

For exemple let's say you subscribe to my application.
You create an account. Is it possible my application creates a wallet for you to interact with the smart contract without you knowing it ?

Second question:
I'm using MINDS, which is a blockchain social network dapp. I can use it fully without having a wallet associated. How do you think they manage transactions so we, users never pay the fees ?

Sorry if my questions are boring and thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. The application can create an account for the user, but it is necessary to decide how it will be replenished with funds. On the other hand, your application can use one account for everyone, and identify users through other methods - from a fixed identifier to an one-time password scheme, depending on security requirements.
2. Transaction fees are not a mandatory part of the blockchain protocol. For example, in private networks, it may not be used. The challenge is to find motivation for the node owners to maintain the infrastructure of the nodes of the blockchain network. The transaction fee solves this issue from the commercial side. But if you find another motivation for the owner of the node to keep it running, then you can do without the transaction fee. Actually, the question of motivating the owners of nodes is one of the main ones when creating non-cryptocurrency networks.